# On Raspberry Pi WiFi monitor mode sniffing - not getting data packets

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am doing **wireshark/packet** sniffing stuff on the rpi. I am using an **Alfa AWUS036H wifi adapter** for capturing. On the rpi, over a period of one minute, with my phone streaming youtube, I managed to capture about 200 packets, many of which were just small 801.11 control frames (beacon, etc.) When the same card, connected to my laptop and I run wireshark, I captured almost 10,000 packets in the same timeframe (still streaming youtube). Does anybody have any idea why? Is the rpi's processor simply not fast enough to keep up? Somehow I doubt this.
**My setup is like this:**

> • Raspberry Pi Model B+.
>   •   One Alfa AWUS036H wifi card.
>   • Manually I set up a monitor interface for this card by doing:
>   • sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
>   •   Then I use dumpcap to stream
>   capture data from mon0 out to wireshark on my laptop for viewing. This
>   results in about 200 packets/minute.

Channel of My access point and wifi capturing adapter was same. Both set to channel 2.
I wanted to test and see if there really were just about 200 packets/minute in the air, so I just unplugged the usb hub from the pi and connected it to my laptop. Same deal,
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
Then capture on mon0 interface in wireshark, I see many more data packets from youtube, and many more control frames, totaling about 5-10,000/minute at peak streaming speed.
Does anybody have any explanation for this? I tried to control for all the parameters I could in switching from pi to laptop, but I cannot figure out why this is happening. 
One more point: sometimes data packets are captured first time I start the device. After that even if I gracefully change state of wifi adapter and start capturing, it do not capture any data packet.

Answer (score 0):

The RPi's CPU load will affect number of packages received through libpcap, even if the network load itself is very light. See my investigation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897856/why-are-some-beacon-frames-dropped). In my case alot of beacon frames were lost, and I offloaded the CPU by booting the RPi in terminal mode (skipping GUI mod) to fix it.

In your case, I would try skipping airmon-ng in order to investigate. Try e.g (if you really want to see managment frame, else skip monitor mode and just sniff `wlan0`):

`ifconfig wlan0 down
iw config wlan0 mode monitor
if config wlan0 up`

And then, sniff manually by either `tcpdump -i wlan0` (with any other suitable option) or why not through **wireshark on the RPi**?.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am already running in terminal mode. CPU usage is only around 15-20%. I am getting all the beacon frames (no drops there) but none of the data packets are captured. I have tried it without airmon-ng (as you suggested) but results are still the same: No data packets.

Comment: Also did capturing at windows machine and at Raspi at the same time and compared results. No data packets in Raspi captures :(

Comment: [These](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=53559) guys seem to have the same issue with the same Alfa AWU. One answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49945/monitor-mode-wifi-only-seeing-broadcast-packets) has got 3 upvotes, give it a try. Let us know if the trick with airmon-ng that @eVAPor8 suggests works or not.

Comment: [Here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5826/cant-check-monitor-mode-checkbox-on-ubuntu?) is another link about setting the channel (even though you mention that they are on the same channel... Channel setting sequence matters

Comment: @Krisz , you should ask the OP in his question or mention him